# Would using a Generic List over a DataTable cause less performance overhead?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, generic-list

I'm a big fan of Generic Lists and use them in whatever project I work on. But I'm currently working on another project written by an external party and finding that the page load is quite slow. In some cases pages take just over 2 seconds to load.

Through initial investigation, majority of pages are littered with numerous DataTable's which are storing over 1000 rows of data. I would have thought declaring and setting up DataTable columns would contribute to the overhead.

Now I am just questioning on the likely hood of performance lag being reduced if I were to use Generic Lists (List) and using LINQ to filter the required data.

I understand there could be other issues causing slow page loading but seeing large amounts of data being manipulated through DataTables seemed a bit of an over-kill.

Comment: With performance issues you don't guess. You measure. Pick up a decent profiler to find where your hot spots are and fix those.

Comment: You should investigate further before doing any changes. Perhaps getting the data for populating the DataTables is problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are *several* `DataTable` objects each with thousands of rows, are those being populated on each page fetch? If so, I'm not surprised it's taking a while - and simply using lists instead won't help, as I'd expect the bottleneck to be fetching a lot of data in several queries. The overhead of creating a `DataTable` is likely to be insignificant there, IMO. (I generally prefer using lists etc too, but for cleanliness reasons rather than performance.)

Of course, you should really be *profiling* the slow pages to find out where the bottlenecks are, instead of guessing. If this is an MVC project, have a look at [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/).

Comment: I thought that Generic Lists were generally more efficient than using DataTables. I guess I was wrong. :-) Unfortunately, I am not using MVC but I shall take a look at other .NET profilers unless you have any recommendations?

Comment: @sbhomra: No, using a list may well be more efficient than using a DataTable - but if the vast majority of the time is spent *fetching data* then that's what you should be looking at, rather than what you do with it *after* fetching. I don't have any particular recommendations around web profiling, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's an honour to have a SO Legend as yourself answering one on my questions. ;-)